# Need for in-memory Data Storage Solution for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-room, android-storage

I need to have API response data centrally stored so that I can access it from any Activity/Fragment/Composable/Viewmodel.

1. I've tried using **Kotlin Singleton Objects** but for some reason, it gets garbage collected or something, and the data gets lost.
2. I've checked **Room DB** but since I don't need the data to persist after the app got killed, I think this is an overkill.
3. Using **Preference** will be expensive due to the constant string<->object conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Kotlin for a while but in JAVA I just use a class with a static reference for such tasks. I create the class instance at the beginnig and asign the reference. This never gets garbage collected.